# use transactions in my MySQL stored procedure with update query how to ensure update is done

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

this stored procedure update 2 tables on given id

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_tst`(IN tkt_id bigint,OUT flag INTEGER)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION,SQLWARNING,NOT FOUND
BEGIN
SET flag=0; 
rollback;
END;

START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE tickets SET status_id = 2 WHERE id = tkt_id;
UPDATE user_ticket_log SET ticket_proceess_time =  NOW()- date_time WHERE 
ticket_id = tkt_id;

SET flag=1;
COMMIT;
END
```

> the problem

is i don't know if the update is done or not 
for example if i pass 1 as tkt_id the procedure return flag=1 which is true but if i pass 10000 as tkt_id which is not found on any of these two table it also return flag=1 what state or handler should i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UPDATE` with no changed rows will not create a `NOT FOUND` state.

You should change your logic along the lines of

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `procedure_tst`(IN tkt_id bigint,OUT flag INTEGER)
BEGIN

DECLARE rc INT;

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tickets SET status_id = 2 WHERE id = tkt_id;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO rc;
IF rc>0 THEN
  UPDATE user_ticket_log SET ticket_proceess_time =  NOW()- date_time WHERE 
ticket_id = tkt_id;
  SET flag=1;
  COMMIT;
ELSE
  SET flag=0; 
  rollback;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: thanks alot that works just very well also need to add ; after  END IF; thank you

Comment: Good catch, I added the missing `;`